# How to insert special character slash "\" in hbase value?

Tags: hbase

Unable to store \ in hbase.

```
put 'table1','rowKey1','column1','This is \ value.'
```

is stored as

```
This is \x5C value.
```

This is the same case while inserting from terminal and Java API.

Why is this happening and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

**Why is this happening ?**

Hbase shell `use org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes::toStringBinary as the default convertor`, and I quote this from func `convert(column, kv)` in`hbase-shell/src/main/ruby/hbase/table.rb`.

The code in `toStringBinary` can explain why this happened.

```
for (int i = off; i < off + len ; ++i ) {
  int ch = b[i] & 0xFF;
  if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
      || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
      || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
      || " `~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:'\",.<>/?".indexOf(ch) >= 0 ) {
    result.append((char)ch);
  } else {
    result.append(String.format("\\x%02X", ch));
  }
}
```

As the code shows, `'\'` will display as ascii code, which is `\x5C`.

**How to resolve this ?**

I don't think there is such need. The reason `Hbase` choose to display `'\'` as ascii code but not the character is that, When encounter `'\'`, you can be sure that you are facing the ascii code.

Comment: Is there any way we can force hbase not to convert '\' into its ASCII code?

Comment: @AbhashKumar it's just the way `Hbase shell` choose to display, in the backend storage, you can read content from hbase use java driver, then you can handler it by yourself.